# pass element reference to a directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass an element reference to a directive. I know that the reference of the element on which the directive has been applied can be obtained by

```
private _elemRef: ElementRef
```

but I want to pass the reference to other element to the directive. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the demo code. I m using a `ripple` directive.

```xml
<ul #other>
  <li ripple>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

directive.js

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ripple]'
})
export class RippleDirective {
  constructor(private _elemRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    // I wan't to refer the '#other' node here
}
}
```

Comment: Please add more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. What is "other element" and "the directive"?

Comment: It's possible this is possible. But, I'd be worried about the code design effects of this. If you want information from that element, you can write a function that reads it in the current component, and pass that information in a `[bracket]="func()"` attribute. If you want to change that element, you could watch an event on your subcomponent. For other uses, specialized tags work well.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass the template variable `#other` to an `@Input()`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ripple]'
})
export class RippleDirective {
  @Input() ripple;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.ripple...
  }
}
```

```
<ul #other>
  <li [ripple]="other">Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How to reset this element if it is input #other?

Comment: What do you mean with "reset"?